# Report for Basic Auth clients - is there one in Office 365 Console?

Tags: office365, exchange-basicauth

How to find out which clients or users are still using Basic Authentication for EWS, EAS, IMAP, POP and RPS to access Exchange Online?

Is there a report from O365 Admin console?

Thanks, M

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using [this Web App which outputs all devices](https://betterlicenses.com/audit_log) connecting through basic authentication (only free for 10 devices).

Using Azure AD there isn't a direct report but you can get the data you need through the sign-ins log page.

1. Access the **portal.azure.com** site
2. Then Select **Azure Active Directory**
3. Then on the left below Monitoring click on **"sign-in logs"**.
4. Add **"Client app" filter** and select all entries below "Legacy Authentication Clients".

This will show you all the sign-ins made through basic authenticated devices in the last 30 days.

[Article with a step by step on how to find the devices on Basic Authentication](https://betterlicenses.com/blog/how-to-migrate-basic-auth-to-modern-auth-microsoft-365) quite useful.